# What are the latest advancements with regards to complex systems?

Tags: complex-systems

I am an endocrinologist, 90 years old, interested in finding out the latest developments in the field of complex systems. I am not aware if this concept is still valid in today's modern mathematical conventions or in philosophical terms.

Comment: "Complex systems" is far too vague. Could you give an example of what you mean by complex system?

Comment: If by complex systems you mean the kind of stuff done at the [Santa Fe Institute](https://www.santafe.edu), I have not heard of anything from them, nor anything about that stuff from anyone else, for the last decade or two.